# Matlab's pan for individual plots

Tags: matlab

I have put three axes on a Matlab gui platform; one sitting topmost and the others sitting down below it. They don't have anything to tell to each other. The problem arises when I want 'pan' to be working only for the topmost, when a nearby button like a checkbox has been invoked but don't know how to do that job. Can anyone help me with that?

Thanks

Comment: Check the documentation for pan http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/pan.html , you can enable and disable it for specific axes

Comment: OK, but there's still something about that. The command that I guess might work is

Comment: H=pen(figure_handle) but it doesn't make it clear what the argument should be in order that to work. It's pretty easy to create a figure and make pan on right there but how could you do for gui axes where there is no figure that I can make it on. My axes have appropriate handles that I have assigned to them so there should be some modification to that statement?

Comment: The command that you need is setAllowAxesPan, check the example 3 of the documentation

Comment: Thank you really! Thank you!

Comment: No problem, I'll make that last comment as an answer so you can mark this question as solved. Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the setAllowAxesPan command, please check the example 3 of the documentation on "pan" http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/pan.html